# Android error: Can't change tag of fragment. Not using viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception

Hi I have a fragmentA with a textview . when i click on the it i go to fragmentB which has a list of items. 
When click on the listitem iam come back to fragmentA and updating the textview with listitem value.
Now when again when iam click on the textview its throwing the  **Illegalstateexception:can't change tag of fragment**

```
boreselect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             Fragment newContentbore = new BoreValuesListFragment();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentChangeActivity.mFragmentStack.peek());
                String tagbore = newContentbore.toString();
                FragmentChangeActivity.mFragmentStack.add(tagbore);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.content_frame, newContentbore,tagbore);
                transaction.hide(currentFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(tagbore);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
```

My stack Trace

```
01-20 00:14:59.819: E/AndroidRuntime(26655): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 00:14:59.819: E/AndroidRuntime(26655): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment BoreValuesListFragment{42a283a0 #2 id=0x7f090044 BoreValuesListFragment{42a283a0}}: was BoreValuesListFragment{42a283a0} now BoreValuesListFragment{42a283a0 #2 id=0x7f090044 BoreValuesListFragment{42a283a0}}
01-20 00:14:59.819: E/AndroidRuntime(26655):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:351)
01-20 00:14:59.819: E/AndroidRuntime(26655):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:342)
```

Answer (score 0):

> It's probably because you're adding the same fragment instance three
>   times to the list. You should create a new instance for each page.